# What does it mean for the torsion to blow up?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Consider the following theorem which is the main result of the Hermitian Curvature Flow paper by Jeffrey Streets and Gang Tian:

**Theorem 1.1.** Let $(M^{2n}, g_0, J)$ be a complex manifold with Hermitian metric $g_0$. There exists a constant $c(n)$ depending only on the dimension such that there exists a unique solution $g(t)$ to the Hermitian curvature flow for $$t \in \left[0, \frac{c(n)}{\max \{ | \Omega |_{C_0(g_0)}, | \nabla T |_{C^0(g_0)}, | T |^2_{C^0(g_0)} \} } \right].$$ Moreover, if there is a finite-time singularity at $t = \tau$, then $$\limsup_{t \to \tau} \max \{ | \Omega |_{C^0(g_t)}, | \nabla T |_{C^0(g_t)}, | T |_{C^0(g_t)} \} = \infty.$$ Hence, if the Hermitian curvature flow encounters a finite-time singularity, either the curvature $\Omega$ blows up, the torsion $T$ blows up, or the derivative of the torsion $\nabla T$ blows up.

**Question:** What does it mean geometrically for the torsion to blow up?

Comment: For holomorphic tangent fields we have $h(T(x,y),\bar z) = \partial h(x,y,\bar z)$, so if the torsion blows up we can say the derivatives of the metric do. Is this something like what you’re looking for?

Comment: @GunnarÞórMagnússon This is obvious now that you point it out, I'm disappointed that I didn't see that myself. This helps a lot, and is in the direction that I was looking for. Thanks again!